# How can I use singleton bean at a listener class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, singleton, ejb-3.1

I have a singleton bean. Currently I start ist with @startup annotation. I want to change this behaviour and I want to initialize it at runtime when the object is needed.

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyFacade extends AbstractBusinessFacade {

/** Static instance */
private static MyFacade instance = null;

/** MyParameter Facade. */
    @EJB
    private MyParameterFacade myParameterFacade;


 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        checkPreconditions(); // At deploy Time it fails. because the dependent objects are not ready

        instance = this;
    }

   public static MyFacade getInstance() {

        return instance;
    }

@Lock(LockType.WRITE)
public void checkTimeout() {
    if (timeOutReached()) {
        //do something;
    }

 } ..    }
```

I use this object in a listener.

```
public class MySynchronizationEntityListener {

private MyFacade myFacade = MyFacade.getInstance();

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
@PreRemove
private void checkStatus(final Object entity) {
    myFacade.checkTimeout();
}
}
}
```

I use the listener by entites

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MySynchronizationEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity{
}
```

If I delete the @startup annotation. I get null pointer exception. How can I ensure that the Singletonbean is initiated at runtime when I need it.

Comment: You should either lookup or Inject the Singleton, not use your `instance` variable. Your container doesn't know when you need the object so it never instantiates it. Let us know what container and version you're using and I can give you an example.

Comment: @Baldy The problem is the listener doesnot accept Injection. For othe types of classes I used EJB Annotation to inject it. But it is not possible for the listeners

Comment: Here a link that will help you get your Bean even in a listener. http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#GettingAnEJBInFacesConverterAndFacesValidator

Comment: @baldy I am not sure if it is the same thing

Comment: @Baldy I recommend adding your comments as an answer.  As of Java EE 6, it is not possible to inject into an entity listener, so you must manually look up the EJB. One approach for doing so is at the link you mention, which shows how to fix a similar problem for JSF.

Comment: It actually is. While the intent was to solve some JSF issues it works anywhere you can get an `InitialContext` which should include your listener. I used this all the time until I moved to CDI.

Answer (score 0):

You should either lookup or Inject the Singleton, not use your instance variable. Your container doesn't know when you need the object so it never instantiates it.

Given that your listener doesn't support injection, you can implement the EJB lookup tool posted here (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#GettingAnEJBInFacesConverterAndFacesValidator) so you can look up the bean.

```
private MyFacade myFacade = EJB.lookup(MyFacade.class);
```

Then when your listener is instantiated and you lookup your `MyFacade` bean, the container will instantiate your Singleton.

Comment: I added the code. But I have a problem with EJB_CONTEXT. I get javax.naming.InvalidNameException. How should the EJB_CONTEXT look like??  
EJB_CONTEXT = "java:global/" + new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env") + "/";

Comment: You might need to change the JNDI paths depending on the EE container you're using. You should be able to get the JNDI name of your EJB be looking at your boot log. If you past what container your using, I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: According to IBM documentation you should be able to lookup your local beans with `ejblocal:[package-name].[class-name]`. If that's so, comment out the `EJB_CONTEXT` stuff and replace `String jndiName = EJB_CONTEXT + ejbClass.getSimpleName();` with `String jndiName = "ejblocal:" + ejbClass.getName();`. I don't use Websphere so I can't test if this will work or not.